# React: How to drag the thumb of the scrollbar on mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ipad, scrollbar

[custom scrollbar in react](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/creating-custom-scrollbars-with-react/)

I'm following this code example to code a scrollbar but I can't make it work on mobile devices (to be more specific, on iPad 9th gen with iPadOS 16.3 on Chrome): I can't drag the thumb of the scrollbar; only the content is being dragged.

This is the full **code**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';

const Scrollbar = ({
  children,
  className,
  ...props
}: React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'div'>) => {
  const contentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const scrollTrackRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const scrollThumbRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const observer = useRef<ResizeObserver | null>(null);
  const [thumbHeight, setThumbHeight] = useState(20);
  const [scrollStartPosition, setScrollStartPosition] = useState<number | null>(
    null
  );
  const [initialScrollTop, setInitialScrollTop] = useState<number>(0);
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

  function handleResize(ref: HTMLDivElement, trackSize: number) {
    const { clientHeight, scrollHeight } = ref;
    setThumbHeight(Math.max((clientHeight / scrollHeight) * trackSize, 20));
  }

  function handleScrollButton(direction: 'up' | 'down') {
    const { current } = contentRef;
    if (current) {
      const scrollAmount = direction === 'down' ? 200 : -200;
      current.scrollBy({ top: scrollAmount, behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  }

  const handleTrackClick = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      const { current: trackCurrent } = scrollTrackRef;
      const { current: contentCurrent } = contentRef;
      if (trackCurrent && contentCurrent) {
        const { clientY } = e;
        const target = e.target as HTMLDivElement;
        const rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const trackTop = rect.top;
        const thumbOffset = -(thumbHeight / 2);
        const clickRatio =
          (clientY - trackTop + thumbOffset) / trackCurrent.clientHeight;
        const scrollAmount = Math.floor(
          clickRatio * contentCurrent.scrollHeight
        );
        contentCurrent.scrollTo({
          top: scrollAmount,
          behavior: 'smooth',
        });
      }
    },
    [thumbHeight]
  );

  const handleThumbPosition = useCallback(() => {
    if (
      !contentRef.current ||
      !scrollTrackRef.current ||
      !scrollThumbRef.current
    ) {
      return;
    }
    const { scrollTop: contentTop, scrollHeight: contentHeight } =
      contentRef.current;
    const { clientHeight: trackHeight } = scrollTrackRef.current;
    let newTop = (+contentTop / +contentHeight) * trackHeight;
    newTop = Math.min(newTop, trackHeight - thumbHeight);
    const thumb = scrollThumbRef.current;
    thumb.style.top = `${newTop}px`;
  }, []);

  const handleThumbMousedown = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    setScrollStartPosition(e.clientY);
    if (contentRef.current) setInitialScrollTop(contentRef.current.scrollTop);
    setIsDragging(true);
  }, []);

  const handleThumbMouseup = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      if (isDragging) {
        setIsDragging(false);
      }
    },
    [isDragging]
  );

  const handleThumbMousemove = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      if (isDragging) {
        const {
          scrollHeight: contentScrollHeight,
          offsetHeight: contentOffsetHeight,
        } = contentRef.current;

        const deltaY =
          (e.clientY - scrollStartPosition) *
          (contentOffsetHeight / thumbHeight);
        const newScrollTop = Math.min(
          initialScrollTop + deltaY,
          contentScrollHeight - contentOffsetHeight
        );

        contentRef.current.scrollTop = newScrollTop;
      }
    },
    [isDragging, scrollStartPosition, thumbHeight]
  );

  // If the content and the scrollbar track exist, use a ResizeObserver to adjust height of thumb and listen for scroll event to move the thumb
  useEffect(() => {
    if (contentRef.current && scrollTrackRef.current) {
      const ref = contentRef.current;
      const { clientHeight: trackSize } = scrollTrackRef.current;
      observer.current = new ResizeObserver(() => {
        handleResize(ref, trackSize);
      });
      observer.current.observe(ref);
      ref.addEventListener('scroll', handleThumbPosition);
      return () => {
        observer.current?.unobserve(ref);
        ref.removeEventListener('scroll', handleThumbPosition);
      };
    }
  }, []);

  // Listen for mouse events to handle scrolling by dragging the thumb
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleThumbMousemove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleThumbMouseup);
    document.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleThumbMouseup);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleThumbMousemove);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleThumbMouseup);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseleave', handleThumbMouseup);
    };
  }, [handleThumbMousemove, handleThumbMouseup]);

  return (
    <div className="custom-scrollbars__container">
      <div className="custom-scrollbars__content" ref={contentRef} {...props}>
        {children}
      </div>
      <div className="custom-scrollbars__scrollbar">
        <button
          className="custom-scrollbars__button"
          onClick={() => handleScrollButton('up')}
        >
          ⇑
        </button>
        <div className="custom-scrollbars__track-and-thumb">
          <div
            className="custom-scrollbars__track"
            ref={scrollTrackRef}
            onClick={handleTrackClick}
            style={{ cursor: isDragging && 'grabbing' }}
          ></div>
          <div
            className="custom-scrollbars__thumb"
            ref={scrollThumbRef}
            onMouseDown={handleThumbMousedown}
            style={{
              height: `${thumbHeight}px`,
              cursor: isDragging ? 'grabbing' : 'grab',
            }}
          ></div>
        </div>
        <button
          className="custom-scrollbars__button"
          onClick={() => handleScrollButton('down')}
        >
          ⇓
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Scrollbar;
```

I tried adding

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleThumbMousemove);
```

in the useEffect() but nothing changes; I also added "touchstart".

It works well on desktop.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what are you missing from the default browser scrollbars that you want to implement your own?

Comment: Having a custom scrollbar in css does not work anymore in iOS 14+

Comment: Also, there are libraries for custom scrollbars but I could not find one that works on iPad (you cannot drag the thumb of the scrollbar)